# $f$ twice continuously differentiable on $[a, b], f^\prime(c) = 0$ for some $c \in[a, b], f''(c) > 0$ implies various statements

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Assume $f$ is twice continuously differentiable on $[a, b]$ and there's some $c \in [a, b]$ such that $f'(c) = 0$. Suppose $f''(c) > 0$. Prove that:

1. there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $f''(x) > 0$ for all $x \in (c - \delta, c + \delta)$.

(I was able to prove this already, but I'm leaving it here in case it's helpful for 2. and 3., which I haven't had any luck with.)

2. $f'(x) < 0$ for $x \in (c - \delta, c)$ and $f'(x) > 0$ for $x \in (c, c + \delta)$.

What I'm confused about here is finding a way to apply $\epsilon-\delta$ continuity (if that is even the right way to approach this part).

3. $f(x) > f(c)$ for $x \in (c - \delta, c + \delta)$ such that $x \neq c$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no need of continuity of $f''$ and the part 1. Part 2 and part 3 follow directly from assumptions $f' (c) =0<f''(c)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

By the mean value theorem since $f'$ is differentiable there exists $\xi$ between $x$ and $c$ such that

$$f'(x) = f'(c) + f''(\xi)(x-c) = f''(\xi)(x-c),$$

and, by what you have already shown, $f''(\xi) > 0$ for any $\xi \in (c-\delta,c+\delta)$

Answer (score 1):

For part c, I first used the Mean Value Theorem that: for every interval $(c-\delta, c)$, we can find an $x_1$ and (likewise and $x_2$ for the interval $(c, c+\delta)$), such that:
$$f'(x_1) = (f(c) - f(c-\delta))/\delta$$ and $$f'(x_2) = (f(c+\delta) - f(c))/\delta$$

But we know from part b that $f'(x_1) <0 \implies f(c-\delta) > f(c)$ and $f'(x_2) >0 \implies f(c+\delta) > f(c)$ .

(*) Now we can choose smaller intervals within given interval, e.g. ($c-\delta_i, c+\delta_i$), where $\delta_i < \delta $, ($\delta_i>0$), and attain all possible values of f(x) = $f(c-\delta_i)>f(c)$ or $ f(c+\delta_i) >f(c)$ $ \implies f(x) >$ f(c).

I'm a little unsure whether my argument (*) works. I'm saying that for all x in the given interval, $f(x)> f(c)$ because any x in that interval can be found to equal a $c+\delta_i$ or $c-\delta_i$, which we found from part b is greater than f(c).

Comment: Your argument is correct, +1 there. But you can simplify it and there is no need to introduce $\delta_i$. Just note that $f(x) - f(c) =(x-c) f'(\xi) $ and consider cases $c<x<c+\delta$ and $c-\delta<x<c$ separately.

Comment: Oh, yes, that sounds much more compact, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

f'' is continious .So $\forall ε>0 \exists δ(ε)>0 : \forall x\in (c-δ,c+δ)$

$|f''(x)-f''(c)|<ε,$

So se can we choose  $ ε=ε_0<f''(c)$

Τhen $\exists δ(ε_0)>0 : \forall x\in (c-δ(ε_0),c+δ(ε_0))$

$|f''(x)-f''(c)|<ε_0$

So $0<f(c)-ε_0<f''(x)<f(c)+ε_0,\forall x\in (c-δ(ε_0),c+δ(ε_0))$

Αnd we are done for 1)

Answer (score -1):

There is a counter example to 1) 
Take $f(x)= x^2sin(1/x)+ \frac{x}{2} \forall x\in(-\infty,0)\cup(0,+\infty)$
and $f(x)=0$ for $x=0$.
[Take a look](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative%20of%20x%5E2sin(1%2Fx)%2Bx%2F2)

Comment: The interval is not closed in the counter example.

Comment: Then $f(x)= x^2sin(1/x)+ \frac{x}{2} \forall x\in[-1,0)\cup(0,+1]$

Comment: I don't think the function is differentiable at 0 (are you claiming that there is strange behavior at x = 0?). But anyways what I'm asked to prove makes no claims as to the behavior of the function's derivatives on points not in its domain (i.e. x = 0).

Comment: To make it more clear.

Your claim is :

IF   $f$ is twice continuously differentiable on $[a, b]$ and there's some $c \in [a, b]$ such that $f'(c) = 0$ and $f''(c) > 0$

THEN  there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $f''(x) > 0$ for all $x \in (c - \delta, c + \delta)$.


The counter example is :

Take $f'(x)= x^2sin(1/x)+ \frac{x}{2} \forall x\in[-1,0)\cup(0,+1]$
and $f'(x)=0$ for $x=0$

We see that f' is differentiable  $\forall x\in[-1,0)\cup(0,1]$
and $f''(0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f'(x)-f'(0)}{x-0}=1/2$
So f' is differentiable in $[-1,1]$

Comment: Click the link above to see the graph of $f''$.It does not satisfy your claim.

Comment: in the counterexample $c=0,a=-1,b=1$

Comment: Oh Sorry for all the trouble now I see you say that f'' is continious .Then your argument is indeed true.